# Formatar Unix Time para exibir apenas Data

Tags: php, datetime

Boa tarde,
estou com um problema onde eu preciso retirar a hora ou definir a hora final sempre para 23:59:59

```
if($form)
    {
        $start = new \DateTime($form['startDate']);
        $start = $start->format('U');

        $end = new \DateTime($form['endDate']);
        $end = $end->format('U');
    }

    $start = isset($start) ? $start : (time() - ((60*60*24)*30));
    $end   = isset($end) ? $end : time();
```

alguem sabe como posso formatar o Unix Time?

Comment: mktime() ou strtotime() nao resolvem? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em vez de utilizar o formato `U`, que é justamente o *Unix Timestamp*, pode usar `Y-m-d`:

```
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d');
```

Veja como **[Formatar a data](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)** em PHP.